# How to use the vscode.SecretStorage?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I'm working on a project where I need to store an accessToken  into the vscode secret storage:
Here's the code I wrote: (FTR I'm not much experienced with TS)

```
let secureToken: vscode.SecretStorage;
//Some code to acquire accessToken
secureToken.store('key', accessToken);
//Some more code
let st = await secureToken.get('key');
```

I am not getting any errors but when testing the extension, this functionality doesn't work. I can confirm that I have successfully acquired accessToken and that it is not undefined when being used the above code. Please help me fix this. Is it the code? Or does the SecretStorage require any contribution points?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ran into the same problem, but I found a way to access the SecretStorage:

```
//@ts-ignore
const secrets = context['secrets']; //SecretStorage-object
await secrets.store('key', 'value'); //Save a secret
const mySecret = await secrets.get('key'); //Get a secret

console.log(`mySecret1: '${mySecret1}'`); //Print
```

Note the //@ts-ignore in the first line.

[Link to Documentation](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/vscode-api#SecretStorage)

Comment: Thanks, this works! Had to fix a tiny error. Fix: `${mySecret}` instead of `${mySecret1}`

Answer (score 2):

Another way which avoids using `//@ts-ignore` is to access `context.secrets` as an attribute of the `SecretStorage` class type.

The VSCode API documentation is not clear where this is stored, I found this information originally in this [blog](https://dev.to/kompotkot/how-to-use-secretstorage-in-your-vscode-extensions-2hco).

Here's how I've personally defined it in the extension I'm developing.

```
import { SecretStorage } from "vscode";

(...)

export function activate(context: vscode.ExtensionContext) {
    const secrets: SecretStorage = context.secrets;

    let disposable = vscode.commands.registerCommand('extension.askToken', async () => {
        let userToken = await secrets.get("my-token");
        if (!userToken) {
            userToken = await vscode.window.showInputBox({ title: 'Enter your API token', password: true });
        }
        console.log("User token", userToken);
    }
}
```